# Getting a link to a specific Google Analytics view

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a GA account, with defined properties and views. Now, I gave viewing rights for a few users to a specific view. How can I construct/get programmatically a direct URL that will bring those users right to that view/report?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: click on the view and you will be navigated to the view reporting. Take the URL and provide it to the users. They should be able to access the view directly by clicking the link. Did it solve your question?

Comment: Thanks, but no. I needed a programmatic way. If I have 300 properties, I need to know how to build a link to each of them in code. I do see an answer below though.

Answer (score 3):

First lets take a look at an typical report url for a specific view:

```
https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/#report/visitors-actives/a40777649w70913173p73156703/
```

Notice the pattern:

```
BASE_URL = 'https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/#report/'
REPORT_TYPE = 'visitors-actives/'
ACOUNT_ID = '40777649'
WEBPROPERTY_ID = '70913173'
PROFILE_ID = '73156703' # Also called the view Id.
```

You can retrieve this information programmatically by calling the [**Account Summaries: list**](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountSummaries/list) API method which returns a list of [**Account Summaries**](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountSummaries#resource):

```
{
  "id": string,
  "kind": "analytics#accountSummary",
  "name": string,
  "starred": boolean,
  "webProperties": [
    {
      "kind": "analytics#webPropertySummary",
      "id": string,
      "name": string,
      "internalWebPropertyId": string,
      "level": string,
      "websiteUrl": string,
      "starred": boolean,
      "profiles": [
        {
          "kind": "analytics#profileSummary",
          "id": string,
          "name": string,
          "type": string,
          "starred": boolean
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

- The `ACCOUNT_ID` is the top level `acountSumaries.id`.
- The `WEBPROPERTY_ID` is the `accountsumaries.webproperties[X].internalWebPropertyId`.
- The `PROFILE_ID` is the `accountsumaries.webproperties[X].profiles[X].id`

Now with this information you can recustruct the URL link to the report of interest for a particular view.

```
FULL_URL = BASE_URL + REPORT_TYPE + 'a' + ACCOUNT_ID + 'w' + WEBPROPERTY_ID + 'p' + PROFILE_ID + '/'
```

Comment: Thanks, I feel really silly. I suspected it would be something like this, just couldn't figure out where the second number comes from. Two questions though: 1 - is this an official URL API, how likely to be changed? 2 - the REPORT_TYPE is something you set when defining the view? Looks like I currently have "defaultid" type in all my properties/views.

Comment: no this is not an official URL API it could change without notice, but I've been using this trick for 3 years now and it hasn't changed since. The REPORT_TYPE is simply the various reports for example `visitors-demographics-age` is the demographics report and `visitors-geo` is the geographic report.

Answer (score 1):

Further to Matt's brilliant answer, you can use the "Try this API" section in their documentation here to get this information without writing a line of code:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountSummaries/list

There is also some code snippets to do this programmatically.

Don't forget you will need to be logged in with an account with GA access for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few points to add to Matt and Adam's answers:

- I chose to build a generic URL for the main view instead of a report. That way a user can navigate to a report of their choosing.  The URL structure is `https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/#/report-home/a[account id]w[internal web property id]p[view id]` **Important**: a user has to have at least `READ_AND_ANALYZE` permissions for the web property in order to access its default view.
- `internalWebPropertyId` is a resource in the [web properties collectio](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webproperties#resource)n and can be obtained through various GA Management API calls. For example, I extracted this value from the response object after creating a new web property using [`insert` call](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webproperties/insert).